# Cant find public methods from a custom SurfaceView that extends Runnable and is nested within a layout

Tags: android, surfaceview, runnable, custom-view

So this app has a custom SurfaceView that extends Runnable.

At first myView was directly used in MainActivity and not through any layouts and it worked like it should. The content displayed through run() depends on the screen height that I was passing from MainActivity. Then I decided to nest the view and make its content  dependent on the layout's height instead.

After nesting it under a LinearLayout I used getLayoutParams() in the code in init() and just then MainActivity stopped recognizing the pause() and resume() functions. I figure I might be declaring the custom view in MainActivity the wrong way but i cant find any relevant sources

### MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView myView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView1 = findViewById(R.id.myView);
        setContentView(R.layout.myParentLayout);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        myView1.pause();    //cannot recognise this function
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        myView1.resume();   //and this function
    }
}
```

### myView

```
class myView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    public Context context;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private boolean running;
    private Thread thread;
    private myClass l;   //imported classes
    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        init();
    }
    public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super(context,attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        int x = getLayoutParams().width;  //happened after i added this
        l = new myClass(x);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (running){
            /*doing stuff*/
        }
    }
    public void pause(){
        running = false;
        try{
            thread.join();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void resume(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `pause` and `resume` method are members of `myView` class instead of `SurfaceView`. You should change your code to `private myView myView1;`.

Comment: Well that was a blunder i did, thxz anyway

Comment: @Tommy also now, getLayoutParams() is giving a nullObject error, can you pls  explain that?

Comment: Make sure you add the view into parent. See more info here `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams()`

Comment: @Tommy my mistake in that last comment, its giving null error on resume(), not getLayoutParams

Comment: Please update your post with latest code and post the xml file, stacktrace when the error occurs as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188572/discussion-between-tommy-and-subham-burnwal).